# libssh's functions couldn't be found on qt and cmake error while building libssh

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, cmake, libssh

I want to use libssh library in Qt and my os is ubuntu 18.04 .
so I cloned the library's file and tried to build it with cmake.
I followed the tutorial in INSTALL folder but the building process can't be completed.
at first I had this error :

```
Could NOT find CMocka (missing: CMOCKA_LIBRARIES CMOCKA_INCLUDE_DIR)**
```

i used `rm CMakeCache.txt` and `cmake` and after that `make`. that was ok, but again when I used `make install` i had this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/home/heydari.f/libssh-mirror/build/libssh.pc" to
  "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libssh.pc".
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

what should I do?
and after building process, is there anything to do with qt? because it could't find libssh's functions obviously!

Comment: write `sudo make install`

Comment: Thanke you, installation problem is fixed, but I still have problem in compiling qt project with libssh.it has errors like : ** error: undefined reference to `ssh_session_is_known_server'** do you have any idea about this? @Waqar

Comment: Copy paste the error in google. does it tell you anything?

Comment: @Waqar nothing useful yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `file INSTALL cannot copy file`
>   `"/home/heydari.f/libssh-mirror/build/libssh.pc" to`
>  `"/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libssh.pc"`

This is a permissions issue. Use `sudo make install` to solve this. `sudo` gives root privileges to a command. Use it carefully.

> `** error: undefined reference to 'ssh_session_is_known_server'**`

`undefined reference` usually means you are trying to access something, in this case a function, which is not found. This function belongs to libssh, so it means that either you don't have `libssh-dev` installed or you are giving the path to the library incorrectly. Since the latter is highly unlikely, i am going to assume `libssh` is missing. On Ubuntu you can install it using following command:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server libssh-dev
```

Comment: purge and reinstall. If it still doesn't work, open another question, as stackoverflow policy is one question per post :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182607/libssh-undefined-reference-error